# Align inner table in outer table td

Tags: html, html-table, alignment

I have a text and table within another table td tag. That inner table has to be aligned to the top-right corner of the outer table. But in my case,the inner table is aligned to right but not top. There is an unnecessary space between text and inner table.

Any suggestions please?

Here is my code....

```
<html><head>  
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="content-style-type" content="text/css">                        
<style type="text/css">
body{color:#000000; font-family:Arial,Tahoma,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:9pt;}
table{ font-family:Arial,Tahoma,helvetica,sans-serif;  font-size:9pt;} 
tr{ font-family:Arila,Tahoma,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:9pt;} 
.header{background:#D2E5FB; font-family:Arial,Tahoma,helvetica,sans-serif; color:#000000;
   padding: 1 1 1 1; border-bottom:1px solid #AEAEAE; border-right:1px solid #AEAEAE;
}
.tableRow{background:#FFFFFF;border-bottom:1px solid #AEAEAE; border-right:1px solid #AEAEAE;padding:3 5 3 0;}
.matches{font-family:Arila,Tahoma,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:9pt;padding:8 0 8 2;}.ResultTr{}
</style>
<body>
<table style="border:1px solid red;" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" >
<tr><td  class = "matches" colspan="  7">
 <nobr>
   <b>Number of Matching Addresses:&nbsp;  165 ,&nbsp;Page Numbers</b>
  <style>
      #Paginator{float:right;margin:0px;}<p>
      #Paginator ul{ margin:0px;padding:0px;}
      #Paginator ul li{ font-family::Arial,Tahoma,helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:9pt;list-style:none;
      float:left;margin:2px;
      padding:4px 8px 2px 8px;border:1px solid black; cursor:pointer; }
      #Paginator ul li,#PrevPage{display:none;}
  </style>

 <script>
     var ga_pageId = new Array();
     function pageNavigate()
     {
         if(document.getElementById("FromPage"))
         {  var fromPage = parseInt( document.getElementById("FromPage").value); } 
         if(document.getElementById("ToPage"))
         { var toPage =  parseInt( document.getElementById("ToPage").value); }
         if(fromPage == 1)
         { document.getElementById("PrevPage").style.display="none";} 
         else
         {  document.getElementById("PrevPage").style.display="inline"; }
         if(toPage == 4 )
          {  document.getElementById("NextPage").style.display="none";  }
         else{ document.getElementById("NextPage").style.display="inline";   }

      for(var j=0;j<ga_pageId.length;j++)
       {
        if(document.getElementById(ga_pageId[j]))
        {document.getElementById(ga_pageId[j]).style.display="none"}
      }

      for(var i=fromPage;i<=toPage; i++)
      {
       var pageId = 'PAGE_'+i;
       if(document.getElementById(pageId))
        document.getElementById(pageId).style.display="inline"; }
     }

      function previousPage(){var fromPageEle = document.getElementById("FromPage");var toPageEle = document.getElementById("ToPage");if(fromPageEle && toPageEle){fromPageEle.value = parseInt(fromPageEle.value) - 1;toPageEle.value =  parseInt(toPageEle.value) - 1;pageNavigate();}}

      function nextPage(){var fromPageEle = document.getElementById("FromPage");
      var toPageEle = document.getElementById("ToPage");
      if(fromPageEle && toPageEle){fromPageEle.value = parseInt(fromPageEle.value) + 1;toPageEle.value =  parseInt(toPageEle.value) + 1; pageNavigate();}}

      function pageOver(lv_this){
        if (lv_this.selected!='X')
        {  lv_this.style.backgroundColor = "#F7F7F7";  }
       }

      function pageOut(lv_this)
      {
       if (lv_this.selected!='X')
       {  lv_this.style.backgroundColor = "#FFF"; }
      }
  </script>

  <table id="Paginator" style="border:1px solid blue;"><tr><td > <input type="hidden" id="FromPage" value="1"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="ToPage" value="4"/> <ul>  
  <li onClick="previousPage()" id="PrevPage">Prev</li><script> ga_pageId.push('PAGE_1');</script>
  <li id="PAGE_1" onMouseOVer="pageOver(this)" onMouseOut="pageOut(this)"> 1 </li>
  <li id="PAGE_2" onMouseOVer="pageOver(this)" onMouseOut="pageOut(this)"> 2 </li>
  <li id="PAGE_3" onMouseOVer="pageOver(this)" onMouseOut="pageOut(this)">3</li>
  <li id="PAGE_4" onMouseOVer="pageOver(this)" onMouseOut="pageOut(this)">4</li>
  <li onClick="nextPage()" id="NextPage" style="display:none">Next</li>
   </ul>
    </td> </tr> 
  </table>
  <script> pageNavigate()</script>
  </nobr>

  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Only suggestion would be to stop using tables like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better if you use Div tag rather then table.
Use like this

```
<Div style="float:left;width:20%"></Div>
<Div style="float:left;width:80%"></Div>
```

Write your desire code inside the div and give width according to your requirement.
If you are designing a form which contain large amout of content then use table.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest fix is probably to modify the styling of the text by making it float to the left, by adding a `style` attribute to the `b` tag:

```
<b style="float: left">Number of Matching Addresses:&nbsp;  165 ,&nbsp;Page Numbers</b>
```

The reason is that the outer table cell contains both this text and an inner table, and the letter is rendered as a block. This means that it starts on a new line. By using floating, you make the text appear to the left of the inner table if it fits there.

A better and more robust approach would be a redesign that uses just one table with two cells in a row. But the context might be more complicated so that such a simple rewrite would not be possible.